# When to perform $.ajax or $.get or $.post in jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

It seems that they are just similar and I am really confused when to perform an $.ajax() method or $.get() method or $.post() method in jQuery AJAX. It boggles me a lot to use $.ajax() that's why I just use $.post() always.

Comment: $.post and $.get are shorthand way of using $.ajax for POST & GET requests, so there isn't a great deal of difference. $.ajax is generally better to use if you require a greater depth of configuration over your ajax request

Comment: `$.ajax` when you want more control over the request(like the options), `.get` when you just need to `GET`, and `.post` when you need to just post. `.get` and `.post` are just `$.ajax` with specific value for certain options.

Comment: You can read more about ajax requests here http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: Thank you @Sudhir :) it took a lot of confusion out from my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All are the same, they are asynchronous. `$.get()` and `$.post()` are the shorthand versions of `$.ajax()`. These shorthand versions do not require any method specification. But while using `$.ajax()` we have to specify the method of the call, post or get.

Comment: @asprin yeah i am weak in grammar :) Thanks.